# assets shopify product page template with api

Tags: php, api, shopify

I'm developing a shopify php app that will add a Facebook like button before or after the product page for the customes to click on and like shop products.

Now my question is how can I push the code into the product page template and also when user will uninstall the app the code will be removed from the template

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a [ScriptTag](http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html) for this - when the user installs your app, add the ScriptTag to their shop. The script that it references needs to be on your servers/accessible, and it will have to handle setting up the like button and detecting whether it's on a product page or not. When your app is uninstalled, remove the ScriptTag.